# Swift - Autolayout 3 views with dynamic widths

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm working with constraints and it was ok till now.

I have a tableview and in each row I have 3 labels. the contents of this 3 labels are dynamic so I need the width of those labels to be dynamic as well.
The thing is, I want the rightmost label to shrink if needed to show the full content of left label and middle label in their full font size.

The right label set to `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`
so the font shrink if needed, and the other labels have fixed font size.
Here is what I have so far -

```
MainView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftlabel,
                                          attribute: .Left,
                                          relatedBy: .Equal,
                                          toItem: MainView,
                                          attribute: .Left,
                                          multiplier: 1,
                                          constant: 15))
MainView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: midlabel,
                                          attribute: .Left,
                                          relatedBy: .Equal,
                                          toItem: leftlabel,
                                          attribute: .Right,
                                          multiplier: 1,
                                          constant: 15))
MainView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: rightlabel,
                                          attribute: .Left,
                                          relatedBy: .Equal,
                                          toItem: midlabel,
                                          attribute: .Right,
                                          multiplier: 1,
                                          constant: 15))
MainView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: rightlabel,
                                          attribute: .Right,
                                          relatedBy: .Equal,
                                          toItem: MainView,
                                          attribute: .Right,
                                          multiplier: 1,
                                          constant: 15))
```

what actually happens is that the left most label width is shrinking and I can't see the whole text inside it, instead I see some of the text and 3 dots after few letters.

another thing I wanted, is that the middle label will always be next to the left label even if there is "white space" (for example if the text inside the 3 labels is shorter than the main view width).

See Image below:
[In the first two rows you can see what I want, and in the last row is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6rc9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Adding width to the left most label solved the problem.

Because I don't know the width of the label from the beginning, I used `leftlabel.intrinsicContentSize()` to get the width, and added another constraint with this width.